# In the Django Admin, the ManyToMany second box doesn't appear for some of my models. How can I display it back?

Tags: django, model, many-to-many, admin

I'm making an app with Django 3.0.8 and I'm customizing the Django admin panel in order to make it more user-friendly for the administrators.

But the problem is that some (almost all) of my ManyToMany fields in my models are not displaying correctly.

Usually, you should have to boxes. On on the left (or above if your screen isn't large enough) where you can select the related objects, and one on the right (or bellow) of the first one, containing the objects already selected.
You can use the arrows between to boxes to add or remove one or more objects from one box to the other.

The problem is that in my case, the right/bottom box and the arrows disappeared.
i cannot see which objects are related to my current object and therefore I cannot remove some of them from the relationship, which is problematic.

I post this because I already had this with a couples of Django apps.

Comment: Can you share the `ModelAdmin`? And the `ModelForm`(s) (if you use these). Django uses a special widget for these.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Well, I didn't use them yet. My admin file only contains the `admin.site.register(MyModel)`. I didn't reached the stage where I'm customizing the admin yet so I basically just use the default ModelAdmin and the default ModelForm.